# angular onclick eventhandler. The name of my object is being printed instead of the value

Tags: angularjs

I have some issues creating an onclick eventhandler in an angular app.

```
<a onclick="OpenCalloutAndSelectItem(this, event, this, '({{fileInfo.id}})'); return false;" id="padocitem_{{fileInfo.id}}">...</a>
```

outputs:

```
<a onclick="OpenCalloutAndSelectItem(this, event, this, '({{fileInfo.id}})'); return false;" id="padocitem_13">...</a>
```

Instead of writing the value of fileInfo.Id in the onclick eventhandler the words "fileInfo.id" is being printed.

In the id attribute of the tag I do get the correct value.

What is the trick here?

Comment: nope. That prints:
OpenCalloutAndSelectItem(this, event, this, '(fileInfo.id)'); return false;

Comment: any reason why you can't adapt `ng-click` ?

Comment: If just saw that I have to move it into the controller
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377632/how-to-pass-angular-js-variable-inside-onclick-function-as-parameter

Comment: why not `ng-click="OpenCalloutAndSelectItem(this, $event, this, '(fileInfo.id)');` ?

Comment: use ng-click instead of onclick event handler

Comment: <a ng-click="OpenCalloutAndSelectItem(this, $event, this, '{{fileInfo.id}}');" id="padocitem_{{fileInfo.id}}">{{fileInfo.id}}</a>

works :)