# How do I pass AngularJs variable as a parameter inside a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-plugins

I have this jQuery function:

```
   function updateProfile(profile, sessionId){
    alert(profile,sessionId);
}
```

In HTML I have like this

```
<button onclick="updateProfile(profile, {{sessionId}})">Update</button>
```

It doesn't work since the `{{sessionId}}` is the angularjs variable.

What is the correct way to pass this angularjs variable inside the jquery onclick function?

Thank you all for participating!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass angular js variable inside onclick function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377632/how-to-pass-angular-js-variable-inside-onclick-function-as-parameter)

Comment: I saw that answer, but mine is a bit different because I must use the onclick for a jquery function  and the ng-click for angularfunction 

ONCLICK is for updates on the table (but does not send update on servers)
NG-CLICK has some other params that sends to the server

Comment: @DuliNini you [should avoid using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) in the first place. It is used for DOM manipulations which angularjs does with directives (that use jQLite)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-click instead of onclick and define your function in your scope

```
//HTML
<button ng-click="updateProfile(profile, {{sessionId}})">Update</button>

//Angular
$scope.updateProfile = function(profile, sessionId){
    alert(profile,sessionId);
}
```

Comment: Not what I mean exactly.
Well I want to have onclick instead of ng-click
So this is a jquery function not an angular function